# Drawing a Cayley graph, problem with extremal edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to recreate the Cayley graph of $\mathbb{Z}$ with respecto to the set of generators ${2, 3}$. Ideally, I want something like the following:

[image]

This below is my try, I will add some more vertices on my own, but what I want to change - and can't do - is the "behaviour at infinity": I want the extremal edges not to close up, but terminate as in the picture above. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]

 \draw[thick, color=OliveGreen] (0, 0) to [bend left=40] (2, 0);
 \draw[thick, color=OliveGreen] (1, 0) to [bend left=40] (3, 0);
 \draw[thick, color=OliveGreen] (-1, 0) to [bend left=40] (1, 0);
 \draw[thick,color=OliveGreen] (-2, 0) to [bend left=40] (0, 0);
 \draw[thick, color=OliveGreen] (-3, 0) to [bend left=40] (-1, 0);
 \draw[thick, color=BurntOrange] (0, 0) to [bend right=55] (3, 0);
 \draw[thick, color=BurntOrange] (-1, 0) to [bend right=55] (2, 0);
 \draw[thick, color=BurntOrange] (-2, 0) to [bend right=55](1, 0);
 \draw[thick, color=BurntOrange] (-3, 0) to [bend right=55] (0, 0);

\node at (0,0.7) {0};
\node at (-1,0.7) {-1};
\node at (1,0.7) {1};
\node at (2,0.7) {2};
\node at (-2,0.7) {-2};

\draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=black] (-1,0) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=black] (1,0) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=black] (2,0) circle (3pt);
\draw[fill=black] (-2,0) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clip the unwanted parts away. It makes sense to use loops.

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{Cayley/.cd,nmin/.initial=-4,nmax/.initial=4}
\newcommand\CayleyGraph[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[#1,Cayley/.cd,#2]
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cayley/##1}}
\clip (\pv{nmin}-0.8,-0.6) rectangle (\pv{nmax}+0.8,0.6);
\foreach \X in {\the\numexpr\pv{nmin}-2,\the\numexpr\pv{nmin}-1,...,\the\numexpr\pv{nmax}+1}
{
\draw[thick,OliveGreen] (\X,0) sin (\X+1,-0.5) cos (\X+2,0);
\draw[thick,BurntOrange] (\X,0) sin (\X+1,0.5) cos (\X+2,0);
\ifnum\X<\numexpr\pv{nmax}+1
\path (\X,0) node[circle,inner sep=1.4pt,fill,label=left:{$\X$}]{};
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A Cayley graph}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\CayleyGraph{nmin=-4,nmax=4}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{Cayley/.cd,nmin/.initial=-4,nmax/.initial=4}
\newcommand\CayleyGraph[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[#1,Cayley/.cd,#2]
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Cayley/##1}}
\clip (\pv{nmin}-0.8,-0.6) rectangle (\pv{nmax}+0.8,0.6);
\foreach \X in {\the\numexpr\pv{nmin}-3,\the\numexpr\pv{nmin}-2,...,\the\numexpr\pv{nmax}+1}
{
\draw[thick,OliveGreen] (\X,0) to[out=-30,in=180] (\X+1,-0.5) to[out=0,in=-150] (\X+2,0);
\draw[thick,BurntOrange] (\X,0) to[out=20,in=180](\X+1.5,0.5) to[out=0,in=160] (\X+3,0);
\ifnum\X<\numexpr\pv{nmax}+1
\path (\X,0) node[circle,inner sep=1.4pt,fill,label=left:{$\X$}]{};
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A Cayley graph}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\CayleyGraph{nmin=-4,nmax=4}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is more then expected. Anyway I would also like to have the edges corresponding to different generators (=different colors) of different inclination. I achieved this in my code - maybe a bit naively - by "[bend left=40]" and "[bend right=55]". How can I modify your code to get a similar result?

Comment: @carciofo21 I added a second version, in which `in` and `out` get used, and the upper arcs jump by three units, as in your screen shot.